GCC doesn't warn about implicit pointer to integer conversion
Background
I was writing code that uses functions from ctype.h to identify things in strings. I accidentally passed the string (char*) to the function(s) which take and int type, causing the program to segfault. It was easy enough to see that I forgot to dereference the string pointer, but GCC gave me no warnings even when compiling with the following arguments:
gcc -o main main.c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -pedantic-errors -std=c99 -Wconversion

I am using Debian GNU/Linux bookworm 12.5 x86_64 and gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0 which is all up to date. Here's a example of the problem:
/* main.c */
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char msg[] = "hello";
    int res = isspace(msg); // char* gets cast to int without warning
                            // It should be `isspace(*msg)`
                            // This also segfaults
    printf("%i\n", res);
    return 0;
}

Questions

What warnings can I turn on to get compile time errors for these pointer-to-integer conversions?
Why does this even segfault in the first place?


Seems like a bug. I get the expected fatal error from clang.

"Why does this even segfault in the first place?" -- Because the function argument of isspace must be in the range of an unsigned char or have the value EOF, otherwise undefined behavior is invoked according to §7.4 ¶1 of the ISO C11 standard.


These functions may be implemented using table lookup. int values cover a substantially larger range than the expected legal input values. Indexing into an array with such an out of bounds value could result in a segfault. "The behavior is undefined if the value of ch is not representable as unsigned char and is not equal to EOF. "


The error I get is error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'char[6]' to parameter of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]

@Barmar: With which compiler are you getting this error message?

clang, as I said above. @AndreasWenzel

Now we see why you shouldn't ask two different questions at once here. There's one answer that gives an explanation of the segfault, and another that explains why there's no warning. You can only accept one, it's a Sophie's choice.

If you write (isspace)(msg) instead of isspace(msg) to ensure that the function and not the macro is called, then the compiler gcc will emit the desired warning/error. See §7.1.4 ¶1 of the ISO C11 standard sentence 5 for an explanation on why this prevents the macro version of the function from being called.

You're passing in a value that is outside the range of values the function expects.  Doing so triggers undefined behavior, as per section 7.4p1 of the C standard regarding functions defined in ctype.h:

The header <ctype.h> declares several functions useful for classifying
and mapping characters. In all cases the argument is an int, the
value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char or shall
equal the value of the macro EOF. If the argument has any other value,
the behavior is undefined

And since this is undefined behavior, crashing is one possible outcome.
As for why there's no warning generated by the compiler, we need to look at the preprocessor output.  The call to isspace gets converted to the following after the preprocessor:
int res = ((*__ctype_b_loc ())[(int) ((msg))] & (unsigned short int) _ISspace);

From this, we can see that isspace is implemented as a macro which uses a lookup table with the given argument as an index, and we can see that the argument is explicitly casted to int.  This explicit cast explains why there's no warning.
The above also explains the crash, since a pointer value will likely be far out of the bounds of this lookup table and therefore attempt to access memory it doesn't have access to.
Library functions being implemented as macros does in fact conform to the C standard.  Additionally, such functions defined as macros must also be defined as an actual function.  This is dictated by section 7.1.4p1 of the C standard:

Any function declared in a header may be additionally implemented as a
function-like macro defined in the header, so if a library function is
declared explicitly when its header is included, one of the techniques
shown below can be used to ensure the declaration is not affected by
such a macro. Any macro definition of a function can be suppressed
locally by enclosing the name of the function in parentheses, because
the name is then not followed by the left parenthesis that indicates
expansion of a macro function name. For the same syntactic reason, it
is permitted to take the address of a library function even if it is
also defined as a macro. 185)

This means that an implementation shall provide an actual
function for each library function, even if it also provides a macro
for that function.


The above also mentioned that the use of the macro version of function can be suppressed by putting parenthesis around the function name:
int res = (isspace)(msg); 

And in this case the compiler will produce a warning for pointer-to-integer conversion.

(It cannot actually be that form, since EOF must be handled in addition to all unsigned char values, but there still could be some cast in the macro that effectively sidesteps the constraint violation.)

@EricPostpischil Likely it's somethihng something like c != EOF && Table[(unsigned char)c] & CTYPE_SPACE

@Barmar There seems to be a few options in ctype.h depending on different defines. One is #define isspace(c) __isctype((c), _ISspace) where __isctype cast c to int like so: #define __isctype(c, type) ((*__ctype_b_loc ())[(int) (c)] & (unsigned short int) type)

@TedLyngmo "something like" -- my point is that it can check for EOF before doing something that may exceed an array bound.

@Barmar Yeah, I didn't mean it as a correction. I just took a dive to see what it looked like.

@EricPostpischil Why? c and EOF should both be int.

@EricPostpischil But the function takes an int, so it gets converted. If it's a macro, it probably has (int)c != EOF as pointed out in the other answer (I wrote my original comment before that answer).

Likely, with your compiler, isspace() is implemented as a macro that includes a typecast of whatever argument it gets to char or int.
Obviously, when the compiler sees a cast, it will just assume, "well, he said so". Macros are not type-checked at all (well, you can't specify a type, so how should the compiler check it).

As noted, the problem is that the C standard allows library functions to be implemented as macros. And that the macros used by gcc's standard lib was poorly written with a dirty cast internally.
Similarly, isspace( &(bananas_t){} ) also passes silently... not ideal.
Whereas the users of a quality implementation expects functions/function-like macros to behave as per the rules of assignment, which do not allow such implicit conversions to int.
They could have written the LUT macro shown in the answer by @dbush like this instead:
[ 
  _Generic((msg), 
    char:          (unsigned char)msg, 
    unsigned char: (unsigned char)msg, 
    int:           (unsigned char)msg)

  + (msg)==EOF
]

To cover all supported integer types but nothing else. But also to fix the 2nd library bug present here, namely to not allow negative indexing in case a negative value is passed. Decent ctype.h implementations probably cast to unsigned char internally rather than invoking UB seg faults just for the heck of it.
And then in case of EOF, we get EOF -> -1 -> 0xFFFFFFFF, then cast to unsigned char = 0xFF.
So the + (msg)==EOF part gives us index number 256 in the LUT in case of EOF. Because making a LUT the size of 0xFFFFFFFF is quite unsexy.

Now for have to work around this from the application programmer's perspective:
The C standard's library section (chapter 7.1.4) offers some advise for how to deal with functions like this.

Any
function declared in a header may be additionally implemented as a function-like macro defined
in the header, so if a library function is declared explicitly when its header is included, one of the
techniques shown below can be used to ensure the declaration is not affected by such a macro.
Any
macro definition of a function can be suppressed locally by enclosing the name of the function in
parentheses, because the name is then not followed by the left parenthesis that indicates expansion of
a macro function name. For the same syntactic reason, it is permitted to take the address of a library
function even if it is also defined as a macro. The use of #undef to remove any macro definition
will also ensure that an actual function is referred to.

So possible fixes might look like:
#undef isspace
...
int res = isspace(msg);

Or
int res = (isspace)(msg);

Either of these will enforce that the function is called and not the function-like macro. And then the compiler has to leave a diagnostic message about invalid conversion.
We may also note that it is good practice to always cast the argument passed to ctype.h functions into an unsigned char, because we can't be sure that the library does this internally as it ought to.
